# mapbox android sdk - how to make a draggable marker

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, draggable, mapbox, marker

I'm using Android Mapbox SDK, and as far as I know, they haven't implemented draggable feature for markers yet. Is there any workaround to do this that works on SDK 5.1.0?

All the workarounds I've found on the internet currently don't work. How do you implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We are currently tracking this feature request in this [Github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2450). Until it is implemented, a solution for this might be to remove the marker from the map on LongClick and replace it with an imageview that is shown on top of the map and the user can drag around the map. Once the user releases, you drop the marker back onto the map at its new location. We do something similar in our location picker demo app example.